# Excel Power Query: How to dynamically use select tables (from Access Database) w/ Power Query?

Tags: excel, ms-access, powerquery

I connected an Excel dashboard w/ an Access database. In the Access database, I have multiple tables, one for each year (see screenshot). The format of the data is 100% identical, just the reference year changes.

[image]

Whenever you run the dashboard, the user is asked to specify the start year. Let's assume the user chooses 2019 which then would make the date range from 2019 through 2020. Right now, my Power Query pulls all data, even from 2018 even though those are not necessary. This is time intensive as it costs computation power.

Hence, my idea would be to loop through all the table names in my Access Database (see column on the very left in screenshot below) and then pick only the relevant tables from Access Database. I pull the below's screenshot information w/ this code:
`Source =  Access.Database(File.Contents(PATH), [CreateNavigationProperties=true]),`

[image]

Here I encounter the a problem. I don't know how to loop through all the entries in column "Name" and to check if they are part of this list. If it is part of the list, I would like the table from the Access to be pulled to the Excel file; if it turns FALSE, it should not be included as the data is not required per the query made by the dashboard user.

```
(loop as number, loop as number, year_table as number) =>
let
    
    Source =  Access.Database(File.Contents("PATH"), [CreateNavigationProperties=true]),
    //code missing: dynamically define number of rows (=years >> here: 2018 through 2020 which makes 3) >> I call it "year_total"

    end_year = Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()),  //define current year
    start_year = 2019,  //refers to year chosen by dashboard user
    list_years = List.Numbers(2019, end_year-start_year),   //defining date range: from chosen start year to current year

    current_loop = loop + 1
    if current_loop >= total_loops
    then year_table = //missing code: would be the content of xth row of "Name" column.
        if output_check = List.Contains(list_years, year_table) = TRUE   //check if given year from table in Access Database is part of list defined by start year and current year
        then //if TRUE, use data for query >> could be smth like this? Source{[Schema="",Item="2019"]}[Data]
    else @Query1(total_loops, current_loop, year_table)
```

Comment: My first thought is that this is a "screwed" database design. Why do you have different tables with the same fields and the only difference between the tables is that it contains data from different years. My recommendation is to fix that first and afterwards everything will fall into place.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right you have several listobjects with the same structure in your workbook. An approach to combine for example two tables could look like that

```
let
    Source1 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="table1"]}[Content],
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="table2"]}[Content],
    tblCombine =Table.Combine({Source1,Source2})
in
    tblCombine
```

Another approach could be to load all tables in the workbook like that

```
let 
    Source = Excel.Workbook( File.Contents("D:\tmp\xlFileName.xlsx")),
    filtererTables = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Kind] = "Table")),
    removeColumns = Table.SelectColumns(filtererTables,{"Data"}),
    extendData = Table.ExpandTableColumn(removeColumns, "Data", {"SP1", "SP2"}, {"SP1", "SP2"})
in
    extendData
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea. I found another solution that worked for me: [link](https://radacad.com/combine-multiple-or-all-sheets-from-an-excel-file-into-a-power-bi-solution-using-power-query-dynamically). The problem with that link is that it always takes all (!) tables from the source file >> extensive retrieving period. Let's say I only need the last two years (=2 tables instead of all of them). Is it possible to amend your code in a way that it loops through all tables in source file but only takes those w/in a certain year range specified in some cells in Excel?

Comment: I think that is possible but without further information how your tables look like and what you tried it is difficult to give any advice. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated my post. Hope it makes now more sense.

Comment: You basically saying to keep all years in the same Access table and reduce complexity at that level?

Comment: Yes, add a time stamp or a field which indicates the year.